# Change width of Qt Maintenance Tool window?

Tags: qt, frameworks, window, size, installation

I want to make the maintenance tool window wider. Users are confused by the version page, as it is truncated and they do not see what the new version is.

[image: Example:]

I tried making a really long title description, but that did not work.

I have not found a scripting solution, but here is my installscript.js

```
function Component()
{
}

Component.prototype.isDefault = function()
{
    // select the component by default
    return true;
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    try {
        component.createOperations();
        if (installer.value("os") === "win") {
            component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/winnow.exe", "@StartMenuDir@/Winnow.lnk");
        }
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WizardDefaultWidth WizardDefaultHeight in config.xml 
see http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-globalconfig.html